# Convert string to Date Format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a string to a date using the function shown here, but I get an error. What could be the issue?

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(date, '2023-05-26T18.48.01.6425261+05.30', 103)
```

This is the error I get:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Please tag your question with the brand of SQL database you are using. You have tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server]. Tagging accurately is important because the best solution may be different on different implementations, and also because tags help you attract the attention of the people best able to answer your question.

Comment: @BillKarwin I removed mysql. This looks totally sqlserver to me

Comment: That is a `datetimeoffset` not a `date`. What are you trying to do? What is the expected result?

Comment: The documentation will answer your question.

Comment: The *real* problem is the choice of using periods (`.`) for the hour/minute/second seperators; they shoukd be colons (`:`). Unfortunately you can't just `REPLACE` them, as a period is correct for the milliseconds.

Comment: Also, did you check what style `103` is? It's *not* the format you have (nothing like it, unless you have a month with 2023 days where you're from?).

Comment: Think about this, this is working -- `Select CONVERT(date, getdate(), 103).... Select CONVERT(date, '02/03/2023', 103)` . See what you're missing?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Who uses `.` as a hour, min, sec delimiter???

Comment: Thanks, everyone. As mentioned in the comments, the issue is with . (period) in the format.

Comment: If all you care about is the `date` then you can just extract the 10 leftmost characters and cast that. But what timezone are you trying to get the date in? Is the offset information in the string completely irrelevant to what you are attempting?

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, and it means - the string data you have, NOTHING will work. You need to adjust your data from

```
'2023-05-26T18.48.01.6425261+05.30'
```

to

```
'2023-05-26T18:48:01.6425261+05:30'
```

And then use style `127`, then it will work

```
Select CONVERT(date, '2023-05-26T18:48:01.6425261+05:30', 127)
```

It will work with different styles as well but only in relation to the datatype you converting to.